# ASP.net manipulate data in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

i have managed to connect to an interbase database and get data from the database and store it in a dataset, i need to manipulate some of the data in the dataset and do something like the following,

add a new column in the dataset called total,
for each row i need to add the 2nd and 3rd column and place the result into the total column.

can some one shed some light on how i may do this, im using the following code to get the data into a data set.

```
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MTD_FIGURE_VIEW1", conn);

    da.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are sure that your column values would never be null or empty then the best way is

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Sum", typeof(double), "Col1 + Col2");
```

In case if your any column's value will be null then it wont give any exception but the total value would also be empty ...

If there can be any null value then try this

```
           dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(double));
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["col1"].ToString()))
                dr["col1"] = 0.0;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["col2"].ToString()))
                dr["col2"] = 0.0;

            dr["Total"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["col1"]) + Convert.ToDouble(dr["col2"]);
        }
```

In this case if you never check for null or empty value then this will give you a run time exception...

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to do it

```
 ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Sum", typeof(double), "Col1 + Col2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is how to *>manipulate some of the data in the dataset*

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Sum", typeof(string));
foreach (DataRow drRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    drRow["Sum"] = (Convert.ToInt32(drRow["Col1"].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(drRow["Col2"].ToString())).ToString();
}
```

**--UPDATE--**

Something like following, using ternary operator:

```
drRow["Sum"] =
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(drRow["Col1"].ToString()) ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(drRow["Col1"].ToString())) +
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(drRow["Col2"].ToString()) ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(drRow["Col2"].ToString()));
```

Comment: thats perfect the only thing is all these values are of type double so can i just do something as follows Convert.ToDouble(drRow["Col1"].ToString() ?

Comment: Correct. I would also check for `!(.IsNullOrEmpty)` before `.ToDouble()`ing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered letting the database do the work

```
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT *, (col1+col2) as sum FROM MTD_FIGURE_VIEW1", conn);
```

PS: you might want to get rid of your select * and use columnames

Comment: Seems the right approach to me, with the only remark that maybe the summing should be guarded against nulls with isnull().

Comment: @Sorin Comanescu yes, it depends on the definition of the database(assumuing the FROM ...view1 is indeed a view) => I would handle that already in the view